# How to get started with the library intel ipp?

Tags: intel, intel-ipp

I got the job:1. Generate a sinusoidal signal.2. Build its spectrum with FFT.For a start, I installed Intel Parallel Studio XE 2011 for visual studio 2010. In vs 2010 appeared Fortran. But the task of writing on the c + +. Something did not get it.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-ipp-71-documentation) should be a good starting point for using Intel's ipp.

You should look also at the [examples](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/code-samples-for-intel-integrated-performance-primitives-intel-ipp-library-71) to get a better understanding of what's going on, in particular the signal processing part is what you are looking for.

IPP is pretty ugly to use, and yet, it is very very fast.